# Python Skew Genome

Tags: python, dictionary, skew

I am trying to write skew genome function but keep  getting Error:

```
Failed test #2.
Test Dataset: AGCGTGCCGAAATATGCCGCCAGACCTGCTGCGGTGGCCTCGCCGACTTCACGGATGCCAAGTGCATAGAGGAAGCGAGCAAAGGTGGTTTCTTTCGCTTTATCCAGCGCGTTAACCACGTTCTGTGCCGACTTT
Your output: ['0', '0']
Correct output: ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '2', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '0', '1', '0', '-1', '-1', '0', '0', '-1', '-2', '-2', '-1', '-2', '-2', '-1', '-2', '-1', '0', '0', '1', '2', '1', '0', '0', '-1', '0', '-1', '-2', '-1', '-1', '-2', '-2', '-2', '-3', '-3', '-4', '-3', '-2', '-2', '-2', '-1', '-2', '-3', '-3', '-3', '-2', '-2', '-1', '-2', '-2', '-2', '-2', '-1', '-1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '2', '2', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '4', '4', '5', '6', '6', '6', '6', '5', '5', '5', '5', '4', '5', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '3', '2', '2', '3', '2', '3', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '2', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

My code:

```
Genome = "CATGGGCATCGGCCATACGCC"
def SymbolArray(Genome, symbol):
    array = {}
    n = len(Genome)
    ExtendedGenome = Genome + Genome[0:n//2]
    for i in range(n):
        array[i] = PatternCount(symbol, ExtendedGenome[i:i+(n//2)])
    return array
def Skew(Genome):
    skew = {}
    skew[0]=0
    n = len(Genome)
    for i in range(1, n+1):       
        skew[i] = skew[i-1]
        if Genome[i-1] == "G": 
            skew[i] = skew[i-1]+1
        elif Genome[i-1] == "C":
            skew[i] = skew[i-1]-1 
        else:
            skew[i] = skew[i-1]
        return skew
    for i in skew.items():
        Skew(Genome)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simpler than you're making it.  The biggest issues seem to be: your `return` statement is in the loop instead of after it; you're using a dictionary where you want an array; the end of your range is off by 1; you have an unnecessary recursive call to `Skew()`.

Here's a working simplification of your code:

```
Genome = "AGCGTGCCGAAATATGCCGCCAGACCTGCTGCGGTGGCCTCGCCGACTTCACGGATGCCAAGTGCATAGAGGAAGCGAGCAAAGGTGGTTTCTTTCGCTTTATCCAGCGCGTTAACCACGTTCTGTGCCGACTTT"

def Skew(genome):
    skew = [0]

    for i in range(1, len(genome)):       
        skew.append(skew[-1])

        if genome[i - 1] == "G": 
            skew[i] = skew[i - 1] + 1
        elif genome[i - 1] == "C":
            skew[i] = skew[i - 1] - 1

    return skew

print(Skew(Genome))
```

> Can you also let me know can I use it in dictionary form?

If you want the `skew` container to be a dictionary, as in your original, you can do the following:

```
def Skew(genome):
    skew = {0:0}

    for i in range(1, len(genome)):

        if genome[i - 1] == "G":
            skew[i] = skew[i - 1] + 1
        elif genome[i - 1] == "C":
            skew[i] = skew[i - 1] - 1
        else:
            skew[i] = skew[i - 1]

    return [value for (key, value) in sorted(skew.items())]
```

I don't recommend it, however.  Dictionaries are commonly used to represent sparse arrays, but that's not the case here.  Another way to implement this is with an OrderedDict -- it would allow you to avoid the list comprehension and simply return `skew.values()`.

Comment: Thank you I am trying to  learn Python with no prior knowledge. Can you also let me know can I use it in dictionary form? If yes then What would be the code?

Comment: @Azia, I added a dictionary-based solution as well.

Comment: Thank you I did it. I am new to this forum so don't know these things :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def Skew(Genome):
    skew = {}

    for base in range(1, len(Genome)+1): # since we start at 1 and not 0 as we should we are adding one to the length

        if Genome[base - 1] == "G":  # subtracting one since we start at one so base at the 0 position  has to be included 
            skew[base] = skew[base - 1] + 1
        elif Genome[base - 1] == "C":
            skew[base] = skew[base - 1] - 1
        else:
            skew[base] = skew[base - 1]  


    return skew
```